# Using typedef struct in multiple files

Tags: c, eclipse, struct, typedef

I have a typedef struct declared in one my headers. Its associated C file can find the typedef, but other headers have trouble reading it.

```
   // In projectiles.h I have 
#ifndef PROJECTILES_H_
#define PROJECTILES_H_

struct TheProjectile { };         
typedef struct TheProjectile Projectile;

#endif /* PROJECTILES_H_ */
```

In physics.h I want to use Projectile

```
#ifndef PHYSICS_H_
#define PHYSICS_H_

#include "projectiles.h"

struct TheProjectile;

void set_Current_Angle(Projectile* PI);

#endif /* PHYSICS_H_ */
```

However, in Eclipse I keep getting "expecting ) before PI" error. Without `typedef` it does work fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should not have another "struct TheProjectile;" in physics.h. Not that I think that really matters here.

Comment: I suspect your problem is/comes from something that isn't what you've posted here, as I took the posted code and compiled it with `gcc -Wall -pedantic phys.c`, and it only told me that "struct TheProjectile has no members", which is expected.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time that do. I tried doing that as well in a separate project and it works without error. I already commented out everything in my actual code, so that's weird. But I must be missing something. Thanks.

Comment: I suspect you are either including something - perhaps PI is a macro - or you have a cyclic dependency on your header files that cause problems.

Comment: You are right I had a cyclic dependency in my headers, which I fixed by shoving it into my .cpp instead. I'll remember next time to include such things when positing my code. Thanks again.